# How to search and display name of a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
playlistname = input("Input name of the playlist")
(playlistname) = ["1", "2", "3"]
search = input("Whats the name?")
if search == playlistname:
    print(playlistname)
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

When asked for the name of the playlist, if the user inputs the correct name of the list I want it to display the list, but instead it goes to the else statement. (Presumably because `if search == playlist name` means it is seeing if search is equal to the contents of the list). 
If you could suggest a way to do this I would greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: your question is not clear. do you want to check if user has given input from the list?

Comment: no i want to check if the users input matches the name of the list

Comment: then what `(playlistname) = ["1", "2", "3"]` means?

Comment: defining the list and its contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear. But are you trying to do something as follows:

```
playlists = {'playlist1': ["1", "2", "3"], 'playlist2': ["4", "5", "6"], 
                                      'playlist3': ["7", "8", "9"]}
search = input("Whats the name?")
if search in playlists.keys():
    print(playlists[search])
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

If the user gives input as `playlist2`, the program will print `[4, 5, 6]`.

Comment: You can just use `if search in playlists:` but I know some people think it's less obvious to casual readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
playlistname = input("Name of PLaylist")
(playlistname) = ["blabla", "bla", "b"]
search = input("Whats the name?")
if search in playlistname:
    print(search)
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

This will print the playlist name if it finds that name in your list

Answer (score 0):

```py
villains = ["The Joker","Magneto","Red Mist","Doc Ock"]
for counter in range(4):
    print (counter)
```

Comment: This is going to print numbers, not villains

Comment: Also, even if the issue @Jakov highlights is fixed, this only lists the names, but offers no search capability.